# update parent form control from user control form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

i have one user control gridview which value changes every second, so I put one-timer of interval 1sec and updating gridview,

now I want to update its parent form label value as per gridview total number of rows, inside timer

i tried below code in user control form

```
  if (ParentFormInstance != null)
                    {

                        Label mylabel = (ParentFormInstance.Controls["lblTotalDevices"] as Label);                     
                        mylabel.Text = totalcount.ToString();
                    }
```

i have one property in user control

```
 public FormEmuHost ParentFormInstance { get; set; }
```

this property value I am setting in parent form constructor: Parent form code

```
 public FormEmuHost(string ISdeveloper, EmuSettings emuSettings)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            this.emuDeviceListControl1.ParentFormInstance = this;
            }
```

Problem is, I always get label control value null in the user control form
[image]

Comment: A better way to do this would be to add an event to the child form. The event would have EventArgs which include the new `totalcount` value. The child form raises the event every time the value changes. The parent form handles the child's event and updates its own label in the event handler. Then the child doesn't need to worry about the parent at all. It just does its thing.

Comment: A UserControl doesn't have to know anything about its hosting Form components. Do what Ed Plunkett suggested.

Comment: If a label is in a container, you are looking in the wrong place.  A UserControl also has a ParentForm property you can use: `Label l = this.ParentForm.Controls["lblTotalDevices"] as Label;`  Agree with the employ an event sentiment from the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **Event** and **fire** it off inside your User Control

```
public partial class CustomMapShapeEditor : UserControl
{
        public CustomMapShapeEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public EventHandler Ev_BTN_Pressed ;

        private void BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Ev_BTN_Pressed != null)
                Ev_BTN_Pressed (this, e);
        }

}
```

And then in your parent form **Subscribe** to the event and **handle** the event.

```
this.childForm.Ev_BTN_Pressed += HandleChildBtnPress;

internal void HandleChildBtnPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```